# spring mongoRepository find by time

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I have the following query working in mongoDB

```
  db.item.find({"startdate":{"$gte" : (new Date(itemDate)).getTime()}})
```

where itemDate is a date in YYYY-MM-DD format

```
  itemDate="2017-01-01"
```

Now I want to write it in a springBoot application, in a class extending mongoRepository.

I tried trivially:

```
   `itemRepository.find({"itemDate":{"$gte" : (new Date(itemDate)).getTime()}})`;
```

But I can't even compile it.
I don't get which method of mongoRepository to use.
The field startdate seems to be stored as timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoTemplate may suit your needs better. It is better to use when there are more complex queries like this one. With MongoTemplate you would write that query like this:

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("startdate").gte(new Date(itemDate).getTime()));
mongoTemplate.find(query, Item.class);
```